# .htaccess forward silently (internally) url containing question mark and variable

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

There are so many questions and answers regarding forwarding with .htaccess, but unfortunately, I can't find any example that works for my situation.

I need to silently (internally) forward the URL

```
https://www.example.com/track?id=X
```

to

```
https://www.example.com/index.php?route=account/order/info&order_id=X
```

where `X` can be any number.

Please advise on what is the correct rewrite rule for this scenario.

I am using Apache 2.4.6 on CentOS 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like the following using mod_rewrite at the top of your root `.htaccess` file to *internally rewrite* the request:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(\d+)
RewriteRule ^track$ index.php?route=account/order/info&order_id=%1 [L]
```

`%1` is a backreference to the value of the `id` URL parameter, captured in the preceding `RewriteCond` directive.

You need to use a `RewriteCond` directive in order to match against the query string part of the URL, since the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches the URL-path only.